# Gulp copy and flatten files & folders

Tags: gulp, build-automation

In my application I have the following file/folder structure:

```
/components
    /assets
    /navbar
        /assets
            /stylehseets
            /scripts
    /sidebar
        /assets
            /stylesheets
            /scripts
    /editor
        /assets
            /stylehseets
            /scripts
            /icons
```

I then have a gulp task to flatten these components into a set of artifacts.

```
var tools = {
    copy: function (src, dest) {
        return gulp
            .src(src)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
    }
};

gulp.task("create-artifacts", function () {
    tools.copy("./components/navbar/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
    tools.copy("./components/sidebar/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
    tools.copy("./components/editor/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
});
```

This results in the following file/folder structure:

```
/artifacts
    /stylehseets
    /scripts
    /icons
```

The problem is that my components folder is going to include more and more components, so I would like my gulp task to be a little more clever.

Say for example, I now want to add

```
/components
    /messagebox
        /assets
            /stylehseets
    /listbox
        /assets
            /stylesheets
            /scripts
```

Now I need to go into my gulp task and add copy locations for `messagebox` and `listbox`.

```
gulp.task("create-artifacts", function () {
    tools.copy("./components/navbar/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
    tools.copy("./components/sidebar/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
    tools.copy("./components/editor/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");

    // having to add these new components in...
    tools.copy("./components/messagebox/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
    tools.copy("./components/listbox/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
});
```

What I REALLY want is something like this...

```
gulp.task("create-artifacts", function () {
    return tools.copy("./components/*/assets/**/*", "./artifacts");
});
```

But this does not have the desired result of flattening the hierarchy. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten).

```
var flatten = require("gulp-flatten");

gulp.task("create-artifacts", function () {
    return gulp
        .src("./components/*/assets/**/*")
        .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: -1 }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./artifacts"));
});
```